# How to transform mssql “WITH” query to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

temp table：

```
CREATE TABLE #temphistory(skuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,shipping_order_sku_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, amount int,sort int)
```

insert data：

```
INSERT INTO #temphistory
SELECT [ShippingOrderSku].SkuId,[ShippingOrderSku].Id,[ShippingOrderSku].Amount,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SkuId ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM 
[dbo].[ShippingOrderSku] 
INNER JOIN @packable_order_ids ON [dbo].[ShippingOrderSku].[OrderId] = [@packable_order_ids].[id];
```

mssql CTE query:

```
;WITH cte AS
        (
            SELECT * FROM #temphistory WHERE sort=1
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT #temphistory.skuid,#temphistory.shipping_order_sku_id,#temphistory.amount+cte.amount,#temphistory.sort
             FROM cte INNER JOIN #temphistory
            ON #temphistory.skuid = cte.skuid AND #temphistory.sort=cte.sort+1     
        )
```

How do you use the “WITH” clause query in MySQL?

Comment: MariaDB/MySQL 8.0 support recursive CTE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: my version just mysql 5.6